# iPhone UI design help

Tags: iphone, user-interface

How can I learn how to design a good iPhone interface, beyond the few docs provided by Apple. Also, what the best way of testing the interface especially when the application is original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try watching the videos of [WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/). They have some on both of your questions. It seems Intruments can do a lot of interface questions right now.